# Find matrix A of linear transformation of two bases.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

If we have set E = {v1, v2, v3} with

$v1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ , 
$v2 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix}$ , 
$v3 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$

and
$L(v1) = \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\\0\end{pmatrix}$ ,
$L(v2) = \begin{pmatrix}3\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ ,
$L(v3) = \begin{pmatrix}-1\\-2\\-3\\0\end{pmatrix}$

How do I find a matrix A of L in basis E and standard basis R^4 and a matrix B of L in standard basis R^3 and R^4?

I'm not sure I understand how to find a matrix of L for two bases?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I think that first you should study the meaning of finding the matrix of a linear map with respect to two given bases.

Comment: I can't seem to find examples for this? I can only find them with respect to one given basis. I am guessing that the answer to the first part is the matrix $
  A =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 3 & -1  \\
   2 & 0 & -2  \\ 3 & -2 & -3  \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ but this is mostly an educated guess since A*v1 does not equal L(v1) so I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

You already have matrix $A$ in fact. Just put $L(v_i)$ in $i$'th column (row) for $T(x)=Ax(T(x)=x^TA)$. Attention, don't confuse, in this case the equations $Av_i=L(v_i)$ don't hold. Because when you are on basis $E$, we have $v_1=(1,0,0), \ v_2=(0,1,0), \ v_3=(0,0,1)$. The last representation in fact was in euclidean basis.

For matrix $B$ you have two option: First one is more formal, that is finding basis change matrix. Second one is to solve system of linear equations $Bv_i=L(v_i)$ and find $B$'s entries.

Comment: In the comment I made above I have what I think is the answer to matrix A which is not equal to what you have suggested. I'm not sure why? Also if I have calculated a matrix C that is equivalent to the transition from E to standard basis of R^3 would C*A = B? Or would it  be C^-1*A = B?

Comment: I add some explanation that address your point about $A$. But for $C$ it depends on how you find $C$! Refer to textbook, it clearly explained it for sure. Also may be even like conjugating.

Comment: Is my comment for A incorrect then? Should a32 be 1 instead of -2?

Comment: Yes, your comment is incorrect. Yes, it should be, I thought it was typo!

Comment: Ok I think I am starting to understand. If I compute a matrix C that is equal to the transition from E to F that is equal to C = (v1, v2, v3) then would B be equivalent to C*A*C^-1 with C^-1 being the inverse of C?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not good at that calculation, myself everytime refer to textbook. Don't afraid it, look at that to don't make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You can write
$LV=U$, where $L_{4 \times 3}$ is the unknowm matrix $V_{3 \times 3}$  is the matricx made from the columns $v_i$ and $U_{4 \times 3}$ is made from the columns $u_i$
$V=\begin{bmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ $~~U=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & -1 \\ 2 & 0 &-2 \\ 3 & 1 & -3 \\  0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$ Then  $L=U V^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix} 7 & -8 & 2 \\ 8 & -10 & 4\\-13 & -16 & 6\\ 0 &  0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$